# Implementing Round Robin Scheduling to I/O scheduler

Tags: android, io, kernel, scheduling, round-robin

I am working on a Problem where I must implement a new I/O Scheduler in the Android Kernel.
I need to edit the noop-iosched.c file and change it to use Round Robin Scheduling.

I am fairly new to kernel development. My question is how would I get started on implementing Round Robin Scheduling with the Linux elevator framework seen in noop-iosched.c.

Your Time is much Appreciated.